# Code signing issue in Xcode version 8

Tags: ios, ios10, xcode8

I updated my Xcode to version 8 after iOS 10 release. Apple made some changes in code signing process and it is now available in general section of target settings. But the issue is my production provisioning profile is showing as ineligible one. This error message is coming:

> "xxxproductionprovisioningprofile" doesn't include signing certificate
>   "iPhone Distribution: xxx (xxx)".

I again created the provisioning profile using same distribution certificate. The distribution certificate is present in keychain too. Everything was working fine in Xcode version 7.3 and earlier. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I faced this too, and fixed it by:

1- removing all certificates of my account from keychain,

2- removing all provisioning profiles from xcode and then

3- downloading provisioning profiles again via xcode and also

4- adding certificates again to the keychain.

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru, welcome. you can accept the answer to be hint for helping other guys.

Comment: +1 for a solution that isn't automatic signing, since automatic would only for less than 1% of the projects I work on.

Comment: Tried all that. Didn't help. Quite typical for Xcode updates, Apple wants do make life easier for the developers - it only gets more complicated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how this works, but if I deleted all my certificates from keychain, how would i get those back as the same ones I used to have?

Comment: This solution, perhaps in less intrusive way, can be automated with Fastlane tools, as I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568005/xcode-8-shows-error-that-provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificat/41395249#41395249

Comment: How do you perform step 2?

Comment: This Worked for me! SO amazing!

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem, I also tried removing all certificates from my login keychain, but the problem was still coming...
Then, luckily one day, I opened system keychain and found that there were more than one distribution certificates added there.I deleted those from there. And then the problem got finally solved :)

So, if you are facing this problem, make sure you delete your certificates from login as well as system keychain and add them again to the login keychain.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This Worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, fixed it without having to delete and download everything again.

I simply enabled Automatic Signing, waited for it to detect my signing certificates, and then disabled it. After that, I was able to reselect the desired provisioning profiles and the Signing Certificated were detected as they should.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if you don't want delete all the previsional profiles and certificates, neither use Automatic Provisional Profiles, try this steps:

1. Delete Provisional Profile from Accounts (cmd + ,), where you can see the list of the all Provisional Profiles according with your user.
2. Delete the Certificate from Keychain (Login - Certificates - Search the Certificate that is causing conflict)
3. From Developer Panel (Certificates, IDs & Profiles - Provisioning Profiles) enable your Provisional Profile that are giving you conflict with the Certificate that you want to use.
4. Download manually you Provisional Profile (it should be green color in its indicator).
5. From Developer Panel, go to Certificates section and download the Certificate that is associated with the Provisional Profile that you updated in the previous step.
6. Double click to Certificate that you downloaded to install and verify that it is in the Keychain
7. Double click to Provisional Profile that you downloaded.
8. Go to Xcode (Project - Targets - General) and in the section named "Singing (Debug or Release)" you will can see in Elegible the new Provisional Profile.

It see that you need to update both of them (Certificate and Provisional Profile), but if you delete one, the another one keep the previous references and Xcode not update automatically. I did this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error after updating from Xcode7 to Xcode8. I dont need to install the certificates.

1. In my case I only have to go to **Xocde ->
   "Preferences"->"Accounts"**.
2. There I have to **login again** my existing account, the login was
   expired.
3. IMPORTANT: After this, **restart Xcode**.

Then everything works as expected.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

As @mgentilc says, automatic signing works. Simply enable Automatically manage signing in General -> Signing, Xcode will create and update profiles, app IDs, and certificates automatically.

Comment: I had the same problem and this working for me.  It took me to figure out how to get the General section mentioned above.  At the general settings you need to switch to the "target", which is the app.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for adding this.

Comment: This actually worked for me too. XCode > Open Project > Click on Project name of left-side > Unclick Automatically manage signing > Reclicking Automatically manage signing > Choose team > run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` should now show 1 valid identity

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps below:

1. Select the Target --> General --> Signing --> select the desired Team (It must the Super account)
2. Then select the Build Settings in Target, keep the Development team with the same with Selected team. Set the Provisioning Profile with Automatic and Code Signing Identity with iOS Developer.
3. Select the Project --> Build Settings. Set the Provisioning Profile and Code Signing Identity with Details information

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issues, but in order to solve it I ended up generating an additional 'App Store provisioning profile' and 'Ad hoc provisioning profile'.

Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to private key in the certificate in your profile not match that in your keychain.
I resolve this by

1. delete all iPhone Developer certificate in keychain.
2. delete all certificate in apple account.
3. using xcode "Manage Certificates" to add certificate, sometime you still have certificate in your Mac, but I do not know where it is for now, and if added successfully, your apple account will display that certificate too, and then you can create your profile with that certificate and download ... goto 5
4. if you use "Manage Certificates" can't add certificate, you can create a new certificate, and do remain steps.
5. finish.

Comment: I found out sometimes requires a system restart as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case my profile had valid certificate but even then it was showing error with other certificate name in it (picking wrong certificate). I had to manually select the correct certificate for development in Build Settings under Code Signing. [image]