# Team signing not working after opening project on a new mac in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, fastlane

I just set up my project on a new mac, logged into my teams developer account and set up correct Provisioning profiles for debug and release, seems ok, I can see my team name, however under Signing Certificate / Status I am getting following error

> Provisioning profile "match Development com.mySite.myApp"
>   doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: My Name
>   (CODE)".

Above one is for debug, second one for release says

> Provisioning profile "match AppStore com.mySite.myApp" doesn't
>   include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: My Company
>   (CODE)".

As I am new to iOS development, I might be missing a step or something of this sort related to adding signing on a new machine?

As a side note, certificates were generated by Fastlane Match.

Comment: Have you looked at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568005/xcode-8-shows-error-that-provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificat . You can also try Xcode -> Preferences -> Download manual profiles . And then reselect the profiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case so many times I have to generated certificate from my mac then it resolved. or may be you can delete old certificate and provisioning profile and reinstalled it.

- Go to the Keychain Access, and delete the development certificate that's related to the provisioning file.
- Download the development certificate you just deleted locally, and double click to make sure it appears in the Keychain Access.
- Download iPhone configuration utility app to delete old provisioning profile.
- From Apple Member Center, download the development provisioning file you just deleted locally, double click the file to make sure it's appearing in XCode.
- then reinstall them.