# Xcode distribution error - Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-certification-kit

I got this error, when I tired to upload app store connect in Xcode.

"App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [a.app/a] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html”

And I can check in **DistributionSummary.plist**

```
<key>certificate</key>
<dict>
    <key>SHA1</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>dateExpires</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>Unknown</string>
</dict>
```

So I tried those thing (But, it didn't fix this error)

1. Project -> Targets -> Select your app -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity -> Debug -> Double tap "iPhone Distribution" and change it to "iPhone Developer".
2. Clear derived data & reopen xcode.
3. Re download certification in developer center.
4. Update pod using pod update -> Restart Xcode -> Clean Project and Build.
5. Revoke iOS Certificates (Production) and Create new one.
6. Uncheck automatic signing and re check it.
7. Build settings -> Code Signing Identity -> "iOS Development" is not included in the provisioning profile. following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43141708/5639379)

extra info 
- Xcode version : 10.1
- Mac OS version : Mojave 10.14.1 Beta (18B57c)

Comment: Have you updated MacOS recently ? Check this thread, it might help - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89187

Comment: @Mrunal Thank you for comment. Yup I updated MacOS to Mojave 10.14.1 Beta...It might be from update MacOS...

Comment: Then you can try the workaround suggest by `jacargentina` in that forum thread.

Comment: @Mrunal Thank you very much! I will try suggestion in that forum thread!

Comment: I did have the same issue and as mentioned in the link it is because of APFS (which is now on your disk after Mojave update). An easy way to solve this is to create a ramdisk that points to your derived data (eg:  hdid -nomount ram://5388608  -> return the disk where the ramdisk is (/dev/disk3 for me), then
  newfs_hfs -v DerivedData /dev/disk3, then
 diskutil mount -mountPoint ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData /dev/disk3)

Comment: @Pierre thank you for comments. Yup, as you said, the problem is APFS. I solved recreate new project in current environments :)