# iOS: How to check SIGNING CERTIFICATE included in a Provisional Profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, react-native-ios

How does one check for the signing certificate that has been included inside a Provisional Profile.
I keep on getting the following error:

> Doesn't include signing certificate: "Apple Distribution: My Name
>   (ABCDEF)"

ABCDEF Being the TEAM ID or APP PREFIX ID

I thought I have included the correct certificate inside the Provisional Profile but I still am getting this error.
So I would like to open this Provisional Profile and see what signing certificate was actually used and if it does or does not match what is being expected.

How to check SIGNING CERTIFICATE included in a Provisional Profile ?

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568005/xcode-8-shows-error-that-provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificat

Answer (score 0):

You can check the profile detail, preview it(I prefer using Space bar) and under `Certificate` section, you can get the detail.

Otherwise, login to apple developer portal and edit the profile to check the certificate used to create the profile.

Hope this helps.