# Provision Profile doesn't include signing certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

I've updated Xcode to 8, since than I can't run my project.

I tried to enable/disable "Automatically manage signing" option but keep on getting 2 alerts:

1. your app id "..." cannot be registered to your development team.
2. provision profile "..." doesn't include signing certificate "my signing certificate"

Im the team Agent on our developer portal I can see my user certificate and all seems to be valid.
When I go to *Xcode -> Preferences -> Account*, I can see our team account attached to all our team provision profiles, but in my personal certificate I can't see any provisioning profiles attached.

How can I add the missing provision profile to my personal certificate and why this happens?

I follow [the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW15) with no help.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565906/code-signing-issue-in-xcode-version-8

Answer (score 23, accepted):

to solve the issue I had to remove all the login keys from my keychain access under certificate category.
now I have only 2 login keys, Team certificate and my private certificate.

Comment: In my case it was trying to use the wrong certificate. Once I deleted the certificate it was incorrectly trying to use, it fell back to the next one and worked with that.

Comment: How can you detect the wrong certificate, which is misused by XCode?

Comment: @user3797599 some people say that they find which certificate has both public and private key. if certificate only has public key, that's the wrong certificate.

Comment: @user3797599 the one cert you used on Apple Developer to create the profile is correct. All the rest with the same name can be treated as incorrect in this particular case (in my situation it was easy to detect by expiration date, the correct one was May 25, the rest were obviously other months I knew are wrong), please note it was **login** keychain that had this issue, the **System** keychain contained the one and only cert which was correct.

Comment: Thank you soo much...u saved my day....I deleted all unwanted certificate and kept only valid one... and it worked....