# Distribution Profile requesting a Developer certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, keychain, provisioning-profile

Using Xcode 9.1, after building an iOS app, I try to archive it.
But I get the following error message:

Provisioning profile "MyAppProfile" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: My Name (X1YZ2AB3CD)".

After looking closer, I see that MyAppProfile is a Distribution Provisioning Profile (this is what I want) and X1YZ2AB3CD matches a Developer certificate.But when building MyAppProfile (for App Store) I was provided with the choice of a unique Distribution certificate (No Developer certificate). So why do I get this message complaining about MyAppProfile not including a Developer certificate. I am kind of lost. Anyone can shed some light here?

In case I give up with manual signing, here is what I get when trying to upload to appStore:

- Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "MyApp.app" target's entitlements.
  Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile from the developer website. Atlernatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove these entitlements from your entitlements file and their associated functionality from your code. Then rebuild your archive and try again.
- Provisioning profile failed qualification
  Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.

Comment: try automatic code signing by selecting developer team!

Comment: I already tried it. That did not work.

Comment: check you keychain! Your certificate shouldn't be expired!

Comment: No my certificate is not expired. So no problem on this side. But MyAppProfile does not include a developer certificate as the message states and I do not see why this seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove certificates from your keychain access which doesn't include private keys. I mean the certificates which does not have arrow(play button type) on left side of name.

and then from your `xcode` select your team from general and unable automatic code signing and then try!

You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568005/xcode-8-shows-error-that-provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificat) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568112/provision-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificate)

Comment: You made a good suggestion, that clearly allowed me to go one step further. But it does not solve it all, I can now archive, but please look at the post  to see the update and look at the issue when I want to upload.

Answer (score 3):

I finally was able to upload.

Here is what I did:
I enabled in-app-purchase in the list of Application Capabilities and disabled it right after. (Giving up in-app-purchase at least temporarily)

There is a lot I don't understand here, but I am just giving this info in case it may be useful for someone with similar problems.

Comment: This was not quite sufficient to solve my issue, but it gave me an important clue! For my full solution see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573190/341994

Answer (score 0):

None of the advice anyone else has given has worked for me.

Finally, I just "unchecked" the "Automatically manage signing" box and then used the drop-downs from my Apple developer account to fill in the signing correctly as CLEARLY the automatic feature is flawed. Do yourself a favor and just don't use it!