# Invalid Entitlements Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I'm trying to run an app on my iPhone. I started by using "Automatic Signing", but whenever I try to run it I get the following message:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing 
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

This seems weird, because Xcode should be creating the provisioning profile for me, so I don't know how I could screw up Entitlements, especially when the app doesn't need any.

I read through a couple other threads with the same issue, but none of the answers seemed to solve my problem. I also read an article from Apple about them, so I decided to do it the old fashioned way and manually create a provisioning profile. Inside the profile itself it lists the entitlements attached to that profile. I'm getting the exact same error.

```
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
            <array>
                    <string>XXXXXXXX.*</string>
            </array>
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <true/>
            <key>application-identifier</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXX.*</string>
            <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
    </dict>
```

I also looked at the entitlements file within the app, it's just the default with no entitlements.

Has anyone encountered this or have an idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573190/341994

Comment: @matt Yeah, I saw that one. One of the posts has some valuable tips I've used before, but not working this time.

Comment: Try the trick where you change bundle ids?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help. My problem was because I recently switched teams, and this file:

`/ios/Encargo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

had a conflict with different DevelopmentTeam id. I fixed it by updating them manually to the current team. Hope it helps.