# Not able to install app to IPAD from XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode8

When I am trying to install my Cordova 6.1 App to the IPAD I get the following error:

```
Unable to install AppName

The certificate used to sign "AppName" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.
```

I am using XCode 8 with Automatic manage signing option selected, below are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Though the certificate is valid, I continue to get the error. What else I have to do in order to make that work?

Comment: It is possible that you have multiple certificates or profiles installed that might be expired.  Try to remove all the provisioning profiles and certificates and add only the one you want to use.  Restart Xcode and see if that helps.

Comment: I have already tried this. Did not seems to be working out for me.

Comment: Rather than let XCode Automatically select the profile, can you select it for you?  What XCode version are you using?

Comment: I am using XCode 8.1

Comment: In my xCode, I do not have the "Automatically manage signing" selected.  Can you try if that helps?

Comment: When I am doing that its saying provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate.

Comment: try the suggestions in this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565906/code-signing-issue-in-xcode-version-8

Comment: sort of a shot in the dark, but have you trusted your developer team on the ipad?

"Tap Settings > General > Profiles or Profiles & Device Management. You then see a a profile for the developer under the "Enterprise App" heading. Tap the profile to establish trust for this developer. You're then prompted to confirm your choice."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending the whole day, I finally found the problem. In the Build Phases section, Under Embedded Frameworks, One of the framework was not selected to sign the code on copy. I checked the box and then tried re-installing it, it works perfectly fine.

[image]